# SASS Compiler for Bourbon

Tags: css, sass, stylesheet, bourbon

Is there another compiler besides using the Command Prompt to compile Bourbon files?

Basically, I am using Koala as my SASS Compiler and I would like to try out using Bourbon with it and when I tried to import the bourbon into my SASS file and compile that file, it threw this error:`Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon.`.

Is there any other way I could solve this by using another compiler? It can be quite frustrating to compile the file every time using command prompt when I resume my work everyday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bourbon imports just like any other sass files. Double check your import code, and make sure you're linking directly to it (use the extension if you have to). Make sure you're actually putting the bourbon files into your sass directory. Then drill down and set your import path to the exact location of bourbon.scss.

I've used Codekit in the past, and it worked perfectly. You don't even have to install the bourbon files in your project.